# Ajax Post text input

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have form

```
<input type="text" id="val_1" value="2">
<input type="text" id="val_2" value="1">
<input type="text" id="val_3" value="0">
<input type="text" id="val_4" value="5">
```

val_1: 1 is id in database
i have field in database called value
how to update data with value where id is 1,2,3,4 with ajax
so val_1 is updated value (field in database where id = 1), val_2 updated value where id = 2

Comment: Please show your html and ajax code.

Comment: i post multiple input, with different id, how to update row in database (by ajax) where number of id input is a key to update, where i have id input text is "val_1" so 1 in val_1 is id in row database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [data attribute](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/).and get data attribute value.

```
<input type="text" id="val_1" data-id="1" value="2">
<input type="text" id="val_2" data-id="2" value="1">
<input type="text" id="val_3" data-id="3" value="0">
<input type="text" id="val_4" data-id="4" value="5">
```

Get form Id in jQuery and pass it to ajax data

```
var ids = [];
$('input[id^="val"]').each(function(input){
   var value = $(this).val();
   var id = $(this).data('id');
   alert('id: ' + id + ' value:' + value);
   ids.push(id);
});
// if You need all id then You can also get like below
alert('all ids'+ids);
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9RdBL/1/)</kbd>

Comment: if i have multiple input with different id, how to post in ajax

Comment: What you trying to get id or value of all fields